# Can't click on a listview item to change activities

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

So I've been dealing with this for the last 10 hours and I simply can't wrap my head around it. I did see that most of the answers to this sort of problem were to set the child items of a listview to non-clickable and non-focusable.

I've tried this in so many variations that even I'm surprised it didn't fix my issues.

So here's a bit of code for you:

```
public class IngredientEdit extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_edit);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();    

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Ingredient> arrayList = (ArrayList<Ingredient>)this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("RECORDS");
        ListViewBaseAdapter listViewBaseAdapter = new ListViewBaseAdapter(arrayList);
        final ListView listView = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.activity_ingredient_edit_listview);

        listView.setAdapter(listViewBaseAdapter);   

        listView.setClickable(true);
        listView.setFocusable(true);
        listView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);

        Log.v("SCHEMA", "BEFORE THE CLICK");
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view ,int position, long id) {

                    Log.v("SCHEMA", "onItemClick fired!");
                    Ingredient myIngredient = new Ingredient();

                    myIngredient = (Ingredient)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(IngredientEdit.this,IngredientEdit2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("INGREDIENT", myIngredient.getName());
                    IngredientEdit.this.startActivity(intent);

                }
        });


    }

    public class ListViewBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Ingredient> arrayList;

        public ListViewBaseAdapter(ArrayList<Ingredient> arrayList) {
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return this.arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position){
            return this.arrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position){
            return (long)position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listview,null);



            TextView nameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_listview_ingredient_name);
            nameTextView.setText(this.arrayList.get(position).getName());

            nameTextView.setClickable(false);
            nameTextView.setFocusable(false);
            nameTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

            TextView typeTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_listview_ingredient_type);
            typeTextView.setText(this.arrayList.get(position).getType());

            typeTextView.setClickable(false);
            typeTextView.setFocusable(false);
            typeTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

            TextView descTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_listview_ingredient_desc);
            descTextView.setText(this.arrayList.get(position).getDesc());

            descTextView.setClickable(false);
            descTextView.setFocusable(false);
            descTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

            convertView.setClickable(false);
            convertView.setFocusable(false);
            convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

            return convertView;
        }




        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() 
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) 
        {
            return true;
        }

    }



}
```

This class is basically the listview activity I have and I'm just trying to get to my next activity.

I should post some XML code for this as well...

The following is the listview layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_listview_ingredient_nametype"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/layout_listview_ingredient_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/layout_listview_ingredient_type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:clickable="false" 
            android:focusable="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/layout_listview_ingredient_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_listview_ingredient_nametype"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is implemented by the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".IngredientSearch" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/activity_ingredient_edit_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The clickable and the focusable buttons I've tried to take off and to take out. Various combinations didn't work, but at this time I'm expecting something to have gone wrong.

Finally, I suppose you want to see my Ingredient class since I'm using it a lot:

```
public class Ingredient implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String desc;

    public Ingredient() {       
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setType (String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType () {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: The IngredientEdit2 class:

```
public class IngredientEdit2 extends Activity {

    private EditText nameEditText;
    private Spinner typeSpinner;
    private EditText descEditText;
    protected boolean changesPending;
    private AlertDialog unsavedChangesDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_insert);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        this.nameEditText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_add_name_edittext);
        this.typeSpinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_add_type_spinner);
        this.descEditText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_add_desc_edittext); 

        //The following will add the String array to the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.ingredient_add_type_spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        typeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        typeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new IngredientOnItemSelectedListener());

        //End of spinner code

        String ingredientName = null; //used to keep track of the selected ingredient
        Bundle position = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (position != null) {
            ingredientName = position.getString("INGREDIENT");
            this.nameEditText.setText(ingredientName);
        }


        IngredientDataSource ingredientDataSource = new IngredientDataSource(IngredientEdit2.this.getApplicationContext());

        Ingredient myIngredient = new Ingredient();
        myIngredient = ingredientDataSource.selectEditableIngredient(ingredientName);

        String theType = myIngredient.getType(); //used to put the type in the spinner
        String[] typeHelper = {"Meat","Poultry","Fish","Dairy","Vegetables","Fruit","Nuts","Spices/Herbs","Grains/Flours"};

        for (int i=0; i<typeHelper.length; i++){
            if (theType == typeHelper[i]) typeSpinner.setSelection(i);
        }

        descEditText.setText(myIngredient.getDesc());

    }


    protected void updateIngredient(){

        Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();

        ingredient.setName(IngredientEdit2.this.nameEditText.getText().toString());
        ingredient.setType(String.valueOf(typeSpinner.getSelectedItem()));
        ingredient.setDesc(IngredientEdit2.this.descEditText.getText().toString());

        IngredientDataSource ingredientDataSource = new IngredientDataSource(IngredientEdit2.this.getApplicationContext());
        if(ingredientDataSource.update(ingredient)>0) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                IngredientEdit2.this.getApplicationContext(),
                "Your new ingredient has been updated",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is I can't click on any item. I see it highlighted when I touch it, but it doesn't make a clicking sound and no errors are displayed in LogCat. The information displayed there is fine. Any way to figure out why I can't actually send a click through and make that onItemClick do what it's supposed to?

Cheers!

Comment: i try your code and its work fine with me could you describe in more details ??

Comment: This activity should basically open up a new activity when I click on an item. However it's not doing so. No sound can be heard as opposed to other clickable stuff in my code and literally nothing happens. When I click an item, an activity should start. However it isn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: ok i will tell you the scenario i made  , i send  arrayList to class called IngredientEdit and in this class list view with 3 items displayed then i click on any one of it get me the new activity called IngredientEdit2  , this is same for you ??

Comment: CAn you post your ingredient2 java class as well?

Comment: I've inserted the IngredientEdit2 class which is the activity that my intent should open. Also, do note that this activity isn't in its final state so it's not doing much at the moment. But just so you can get a glimpse of what I'm trying to achieve, I've posted it above.

Comment: Does logcat show "onItemClick fired!"?

Comment: No, it doesn't. When that happens, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. You've been great. The problem was easier than I thought. The previous class was starting an intent with a similar layout and I didn't even realize it.